# Lit element dynamic value in property constructor

Tags: javascript, dynamic, lit-element

I have for example this property:

```
@property({ type: Object }) searchObject = [{
      title: "service",
      key: "provider_id",
      operators: ReadableOperator.equals,
      data: this.listOfProviders,
      selector: {
        select: {
          options: {
            data: this.listOfProviders || [],
            key: "providerId",
            value: "name",
          },
        },
      }]
```

The **this.listOfProviders** that you see as values in the object is dynamic and is calculated later.

Regarding the needs I have, I'm changing values of some keys in the parent component and then pass it to his child component.

I'm saying that because it's important that I can still refer to this property in the parent's code and change value if I need to.

**The issue is:** Lit element does not allow me have dynamic value in the constructor, once it is created, even if this.listOfProviders changes, searchObjet will not be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

As you've noted, the assignment here only happens once when instantiating the component. To make sure `searchObject` is updated when `listOfProviders` changes, you can do that in [`willUpdate()`](https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/#willupdate) lifecycle.

For example, assuming `listOfProviders` is also a reactive property:

```
willUpdate(changedProperties: PropertyValues<this>) {
  if (changedProperties.has('listOfProviders')) {
    this.searchObject = [{
      title: "service",
      key: "provider_id",
      operators: ReadableOperator.equals,
      data: this.listOfProviders,
      selector: {
        select: {
          options: {
            data: this.listOfProviders,
            key: "providerId",
            value: "name",
          },
        },
    }];
  }
}
```

Perhaps you'd want a function that takes the variable portion and constructs the `searchObject` so you don't have this duplication.

Some things I'm not sure about which could depend on your use case is whether `searchObject` needs to be an array with an object inside it like that, and whether it actually needs to even be a reactive property.

Comment: hey @Augustine, thank you for your answer. Regarding the end of your message, in fact my property searchObject is actually an array of objects. And there's only one specific object that takes this.listOfProviders as data. And for your second thougth I don't rellay understand what you mean bye "and whether it actually needs to even be a reactive property.".

Comment: @Simon To clarify, adding the `@property()` decorator makes that property "reactive", that is, Lit will be watching for when the value is changed, and trigger an update if it does. If you're not directly updating `searchObject` and it only changes by embedded variables like `listOfProviders` changing, you don't need to add the `@property()` decorator and using `willUpdate()` to update it is fine. If you do have other ways of updating that object, care must be taken to actually trigger an update https://lit.dev/docs/components/properties/#mutating-properties